# Use .htaccess to remove file extensions but also allow set a homepage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having a problem using the .htaccess file. I have created the file and set it up so that I don't have to type file extensions in the URL. Unfortunately, this has created a new problem. I used to be able to type localhost/project and it would display index.php. But now if I type localhost/project it displays a Server Error 500. Does anyone know how I can solve this error?

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: that means either there is an error in the .htaccess file or you've changed something. post your .htaccess.

Comment: @unixmiah I added it in the main post - By the way it works if I go to localhost/project/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also check the `!-d` with the request filename, may as well add all the right conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that `/project` is a directory, and mod_dir automatically redirects that to `/project/`, and that matches the first rule, so it turns to `/project.php`, which isn't a file.

Comment: Thank You, this works but now the file extension remover isn't working

Comment: @Flibio I see no "remover" in your htaccess rules

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! It works perfectly now - I had just made a simple mistake in the above comment

Comment: you can add project.php if you want to have that page rewritten